# Native.loadLibrary() returns null when project is a gradle dependency

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, dll, jna

Implemented a java driver project which exploits some `.dll` files with help of JNA. It works pretty well as a project when i build and run. However, I am not able to load `.dll` file when this driver project is jarred and become a dependency to another bigger project.

I am using `Native.loadLibrary(LIBRARY_NAME, MY_INTERFACE.class)` syntax to load the library in the driver project. This line successfully loads my library in the driver project but returns `null` when it is a dependency to another project. How can i debug and find out where the problem is?

To reproduce this behavior:

`OS: Windows 10
IDE: Intellij Community 2018.2
Java: 1.8.0_191
driver project: https://github.com/ClearControl/GS16AO64c
parent project: https://github.com/AhmetCanSolak/clearcontrol`

Comment: Try moving the dll to the `resources` directory, then use `Native.extractFromResourcePath` to extract it to the file system, then pass that `File`'s path to `loadLibrary`.

Comment: Hmm, actually, looking at the source for `loadLibrary`, it attempts to do just that as a last resort. If you move the DLL to the root of your resources directory and load the library with `/dll-name.dll`, does it work?

Comment: `Native.extractFromResourcePath()` requires try/catch block which we can not have in an interface file.

Comment: I tried moving dll and lib file in the `lib.win64` package to resources root, however, it still does not solve the problem.

Comment: I am still able to run the tests in the driver project, however, i am not able call driver from parent project as a `gradle` dependency.

Comment: Also can you tell me where native.loadLibrary() looks when it is called inside a gradle module? how to debug this?

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at the [project's source on Github](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). Pick the correct version from the tags and take a peek at the `Native.java` file. I would probably try inserting a *breakpoint* and see where the loader is trying to find the file.

Comment: exactly that's what i am trying to do. Using intellij ide and forcing to enter on the breakpoint but could not get in the library. Now also started reading `Native.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. JNA's `Native.loadLibrary()` was not able to access any non-class element from a jar. I copied the resource .dll files into temp files and first load them with:

`System.load(tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());`

then use `Native.loadLibrary()`. This way it works.